# Best/most common way to update UI from background thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, nsnotificationcenter

I was posting notifications to the `NSNotficiationCenter` everytime I needed to get out of a closure to update the UI, but this started to get a bit tedious and made me wondering if there was a better way. After a quick search I found out that you can just dispatch to the main queue like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update some UI
}
```

This approach is less code for sure, but I wonder if it improves readability. So my question is, what is considered "the way to go" in Swift to update UI from a background thread?

Comment: I don't think there is 'one way to go' with this (at least api wise), but what you're showing here is pretty common. There are a couple of open source helpers that wrap gcd calls and add some syntactic sugar. [Here is one of them](https://github.com/duemunk/Async)

Comment: This is WAY cheaper than notifications, and much more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
   // do some background task
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      // update some UI
   }
}
```

Comment: also considering that this is way cheaper like @PEEJWEEJ said under my question I'll go with this.